# Gitbash is not setting environment variable correctly

Tags: node.js, git-bash, npm-debug

I am trying to use `npm install debug` in my node server.

```
var debugModule = require('debug');
var debugMainApp = debugModule('debugMainApp')

const express = require('express');

const app =  express();

const port ='3000';
const domain = 'localhost';

app.listen(port,domain,()=>{
     debugMainApp('Server started in port: ' + port + ' hostname: ' + domain);
});
```

`debugMainApp('Server started in port: ' + port + ' hostname: ' + domain);` is not printing anything to console.

***My attempts to solve this issue***
By setting the attribute `debugMain.enabled = true` manually `debugMainApp('Server started in port: ' + port + ' hostname: ' + domain);` printed the following into console:

```
mainApp Server started in port: 3000 hostname: localhost +0ms
```

To my understanding  this `debugMain.enabled` attribute should be set automatically when an environment variable that matches the string `debugModule('this_String')` is set.

Here is how I set the environment variable and start my server

```
$ DEBUG=debugMainApp & node server.js
```

But it seems that the latter is not setting the environment variable properly.

***Questions***

1. If you think my environment variable theory is right. What is the correct way to set an environment variable using a GitBash command line? e.g.`$ DEBUG=mainApp & node server.js`
2. Could it be something else?

Thanks in advance.

***More relevant info:***

My OS: *Windows 10*
GitBash Version: *2.13.0.windows.1*
NodeJS version: *6.10.3*

***RESOLUTION***
[image]

Comment: Can you try `DEBUG=debugMain node server.js`

Comment: _when an environment variable that matches the string debugModule('this_String') is set._ Yes, this string would be `mainApp` but you're calling it with `debugMain`.

Comment: It was a typo on my part, these strings DO match on my code. The '&' in $ DEBUG=debugMain & node server.js was messing things up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The & would indicate to the bash to launch a process in background.

The right syntax is:

```
DEBUG=mainApp node server.js
```

See more at "[Why is setting a variable before a command legal in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/126942/7490)"

> A simple command is a sequence of optional variable assignments followed by blank-separated words and redirections, and terminated by a control operator.